# Input field for positive and negative floating point values except of 0

Tags: html, forms, validation

How can I restrict a number input field to all possible positive and negative floating point values except of 0 using HTML5 without Javascript?

```
<input type="number" name="allBut0"/> <!-- This sadly allows 0 value. -->
```

Comment: I dont think that this is possibule without javascript. The nearest thing would be to use min & max attribute but then you could still input 0 if its in the range of the two.